# Displaying PHP search results on screen

Tags: php, postgresql

I have complied a php search page but i am having trouble working out a page display issue that i would like to have.

My data return query is correct and i believe my issue is how i display the information on screen.

Example table

```
userid    Questionnaire ID      QID     Question        Answer 
  1        38                   846     Question 1      Answer 1
  1        38                   849     Question 2      Answer 2
  1        38                   850     Question 3      Answer 3
  1        38                   869     Question 4      Answer 4
  2        38                   846     Question 1      Answer 1
  2        38                   849     Question 2      Answer 2
  2        38                   850     Question 3      Answer 3
  2        38                   869     Question 4      Answer 4
```

what i would like to display

```
userid
1
Questionaire ID
38
Question 1
Answer 1
Question 2
Answer 2
Question 3
Answer 3
Question 4
Answer 4
PAGE BREAK (if possible)
userid
2
Questionaire ID
38
Question 1
Answer 1
Question 2
Answer 2
Question 3
Answer 3
Question 4
Answer 4
```

What I am getting is this

```
userid
1
Questionaire ID
38
Question 1
Answer 1
userid
1
Questionaire ID
38
Question 2
Answer 2
userid
1
Questionaire ID
38
Question 3 etc


userid
2
Questionaire ID
38
Question 1
Answer 1
userid
2
Questionaire ID
38
Question 2
Answer 2
userid
2
Questionaire ID
38
Question 3 etc
```

I believe I have to use an array with foreach from doing my searches on the internet but i am new to PHP and self teaching so find it difficult to understand the way it works.
This is how i echo my results

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {


echo '<div style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:15px; margin-bottom: 10px;">';
echo '<p><strong>User ID:</strong><br> ' . $row['userid'] . '</p>';
echo '<p><strong>Questionaire ID:</strong><br> ' . $row['Questionaire ID'] . '</p>';
echo '<p><strong>Question:</strong><br> ' . $row['Question'] . '</p>';
echo '<p><strong>Answer:</strong><br> ' . $row['Answer'] . '</p>';
echo '</div>';
```

Sorry i updated my post to be alittle clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the results in an array and then print them to the screen.

```
//I have never seen pg_fetch_array()
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $new_arr[] = $row;
}
//print each row
foreach($new_arr as $new){
  echo $new;
}
```

Comment: our server uses  postgres hence the pg_fetch_array http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php

Comment: i see from researching mainly at PHP.net that your approach is how i need to do my data return but after 2 days of banging my head on the table i can't get it to work. I know because  im  echoing out my query and that shows on my page but my php is stalling after that .  I have watch lots of youtube videos and read countless pages including here but none of them  address what i am trying to do. Would you mind showing me using the example please?

Comment: @Gazzo1967 what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Im new to php and from my example i would like to display my results as

Comment: Irancheta Im new to php and i cant implement the array and foreach correctly. This is my error from a script i run on the php page Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/site/site/forms/application_search.php on line 115 Number of rows : 26. From my example i would like to display my results as user 1, Questionaire ID then Question 1, Answer, Question 2 Answer 2 instead i get user1, questionaire id, Question 1,Answer 1, then next row user 1, Questionaire id, Question 2, Answer 2.   Im a visual learner and learn from seeing examples

Comment: Here is my code
$result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
if (!$result) {die('Error in SQL query: ' . pg_last_error());}
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
$data[] = $row;}
foreach($result as $new){
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><p><strong>Job Reference Number:</strong><br>  ' . $new[3] . '</p></td>';
echo ' <td><p><strong>Job Title:</strong><br>' . $new[4] . '</p></td>';
echo '<td><p><strong>Question:</strong><br> ' . $new[16] . '</p></td>';
echo '<td><p><strong>Answer:</strong><br> ' . $new[17] . '</p></td>';
             echo '</tr>';
             echo '</table>';
}

Comment: @ Josan Iracheta Appreciate your time looking at this for me

Comment: @Gazzo1967 I see your error. Your code should be like this: `foreach($data as $new)`

Comment: @ Josan Iracheta thank you my page now works :) but the returns still show all data for each row and does not give me the desired view. I think i may have to rethink mysql query utilising the QID column as that is the unique separator rather than try to fix with php to show user 1, questionnaire ID once then show each question & Answer without the full row being echoed :(

Comment: @Gazzo1967 okay now I understand what you are trying to do. You want to show question and answer values for each unique user. In order to do that, you will have to manipulate the data yourself once you have fetched it from the table.

Comment: @ Josan Iracheta I thought that might be the case so of i go to rewrite my query. will mak this a answers by yourself and thank you for you hepl...at least i understand foreach application now :)

Comment: @Gazzo1967 you don't have to change the query. Once you get the data from the table and store it in an array, you need to use that array to group the data by userid and store it in a new array. Then you will print the results of the new array onto the page.

Comment: @ Josan Iracheta just looked up what you suggested but i think its a little beyond me as i an very new to php :( Only just got understanding of foreach with your help lol

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>userid</th>
    <th>Questionnaire ID</th>
    <th>QID</th>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>Answer</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<th>'.$row['userid'].'</th>';
     echo '<th>'.$row['Questionaire ID'].'</th>';
     echo '<th>'.$row['QID'].'</th>';
     echo '<th>'.$row['Question'].'</th>';
     echo '<th>'.$row['Answer'].'</th>';
     echo '</tr>'
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: This returns what i already have unless i am doing it wrong. Question and Answer columns have multiple rows relating to 1 userid the column QID is the variable against each question